# PowerShell: Appending HTML to Property with Multiple Values

Tags: powershell

How am I able to append some HTML tags (`<td></td>`) to an existing property?

I've been stuck on this one for a little while now with no luck...

```
$teamConfig = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team1'
        TeamEmail = 'team1@domain.tld'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team2'
        TeamEmail = 'team2@domain.tld'
    }
)

$query = "select * from INCAutomation"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'AyushTest'

$teamTickets = foreach($team in $teamConfig){
  # Filter tickets based on team name
  $ticketIds = $results |Where-Object TeamName -eq $team.TeamName |Select -ExpandProperty TicketID

  # Output a single object per team, with all ticket IDs attached
  $team |Select TeamName,TeamEmail,@{Name='TicketID';Expression={$ticketIds}}
}

$teamTickets
```

Output:

```
TeamName TeamEmail        TicketID
-------- ---------        --------
Team1    team1@domain.tld {INC0001, INC0002, INC0003, INC0004}
Team2    team2@domain.tld {INC0005, INC0006, INC0007}
```

Desired output:

```
TeamName TeamEmail        TicketID
-------- ---------        --------
Team1    team1@domain.tld {<td>INC0001</td>, <td>INC0002</td>, <td>INC0003</td>, <td>INC0004</td>}
Team2    team2@domain.tld {<td>INC0005</td>, <td>INC0006</td>, <td>INC0007</td>}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should run them through a loop and modify each string to add the desired text. You can do that and add the modified strings to a new object, which you can use to replace the original `$ticketIds` variable as the `Expression` in your output.

Here's an example of your code, modified:

```
$teamConfig = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team1'
        TeamEmail = 'team1@domain.tld'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team2'
        TeamEmail = 'team2@domain.tld'
    }
)

$query = "select * from INCAutomation"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'AyushTest'

$teamTickets = foreach($team in $teamConfig){
    # Filter tickets based on team name
    $ticketIds = $results |Where-Object TeamName -eq $team.TeamName |Select -ExpandProperty TicketID

    # Create an empty array
    $ticketIdArray = @()
    foreach ($id in $ticketIds) {
        # Modify the string to include the desired output
        $thisId = '<td>' + "$id" + '</td>'
        # Add the modified string to the empty array
        $ticketIdArray += $thisId
    }

    # Output a single object per team, with all ticket IDs attached
    $team |Select TeamName,TeamEmail,@{Name='TicketID';Expression={$ticketIdArray}}
}

$teamTickets
```